# how to check if the object is base class type

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following inheritance hierarchy

```
class A{
  virtual bool fun() = 0;
};

class B: public A{
...
}

class C: public B{
...
}

class D: public C{
...
}

class E: public B{
...
}
```

in the main program I am executing like

```
for(auto pA: ObjVector)
{
   if(pA->fun()){
       ...
   }
}
```

Now I would like to know pA is contains the base class B object.
As far as I know 2 ways

1. `dynamic_cast` the object and test for all derived classes if it fails
   for all `dynamic_casts` and only pass for `B` we are sure that the
   object is of type `B`
2. Add one more interface method that will return the type `enumeration`
   value and identify the `B` object.

Is there is any other method to identifying the `B` class?

Comment: If your writing code that needs to know what object you are dealing with, it's more than likely you have a flaw in your design.

Comment: I am fixing an issue in the existing code, this design is given by the customer and we not not supposed to change his design.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the typeid operator. For example

```
if (typeid(*pA) == typeid(B)) {
    /* ... ptr points to a B ... */
}
```

this work **ONLY** when `pA` is exactly B

[typeid - documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

Comment: thanks for this, let me test with your solution and I will update here. I never used typeid before

Comment: Got my vote, for the method that does *exact* matching in a single test.

Comment: Thanks!! your solution fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

I think those are the only options.

I would strongly discourage use of `enum`s to identify object types. It quickly leads to violation of the [Open/Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

Use of `dynamic_cast` is a lot better but it's worthwhile to take a hard look at the problem to make sure that it is absolutely essential -- that you cannot accomplish what you want to using `virtual` function no matter how you try it.